# Why does with scala.math.BigInt(-1).mod(-2) return -3?

Tags: scala, biginteger, modulo

I was looking into the difference between `x % y` and `x mod y`, which I believe I understood for positive values of `y`.

During experimentation, it came up that `scala.math.BigInt(-1) mod -2` evaluates as `-3`, which makes absolutely no sense to me. I did not find a formal description of scala's `BigInt` behavior, but `Java`'s says it should throw an exception if the second argument is negative.

What's going on with this?

Comment: [docs](https://dotty.epfl.ch/api/scala/math/BigInt.html#mod-7a0) state that second argument is expected to be positive number (**that** A positive number).

Comment: @GuruStron: So it doesn't throw any exceptions for any BigInt method? I don't really know Scala but for example something like `modInverse` has to throw an exception if the inverse doesn't exist.

Comment: Which version of Scala are you using? Using Scala 3 and Scala 2.13.8 I can reproduce the behaviour you observed, but using Scala 2.12.12 I get an error "java.lang.ArithmeticException: BigInteger: modulus not positive".

Comment: @JarrodBakerThis was using Scala 3.